# How did William Turner survive?

Tags: plot-explanation, pirates-of-the-caribbean, dead-men-tell-no-tales

In movie *Pirates of Caribbean: Salazar's Revenge*, lead actor is trying to remove all of the curses of the sea so he can remove the old curse of The Flying Dutchman and eventually release his father William Turner from a curse. and in the end he got success doing that but one thing I don't understand is how William Turner is alive without his heart

As per curse, The Flying Dutchman must have a captain and whoever kills the captain be the next captain by giving his or her heart to the ship.

So, how did William Turner survive natural death after curse has been released?

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask a **new** question. don't edit your question to fundamentally change the old one. I've removed the changes for you.